# Image Classification in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm preparing for the Azure Machine Learning exam, and here is a question confuses me.

> You are designing an Azure Machine Learning workflow. You have a
> dataset that contains two million large digital photographs. You plan
> to detect the presence of trees in the photographs. You need to ensure
> that your model supports the following:
>
> Solution: You create a Machine
> Learning experiment that implements the Multiclass Decision Jungle
> module. Does this meet the goal?
>
> Solution: You create a Machine Learning experiment that implements the
> Multiclass Neural Network module. Does this meet the goal?

The answer for the first question is No while for second is Yes, but I cannot understand why Multiclass Decision Jungle doesn't meet the goal since it is a classifier. Can someone explain to me the reason?

Comment: You sure the answer to the 2nd question is Yes? After all, trees/no-trees sounds like a binary problem, and not a multiclass one...

Comment: @desertnaut can a multiclass classifier deal with binary classification problem?

Comment: The question itself sounds absurd; either you have a binary classification problem and you use a binary classifier, or you have a multi-class problem and you employ a multi-class classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this is part of a series of questions that present the same scenario. And there should be definitely some constraints in the scenario. 
Moreover if you have a look on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/multiclass-neural-network):

> However, recent research has shown that deep neural networks (DNN)
>   with many layers can be very effective in complex tasks such as image
>   or speech recognition. The successive layers are used to model
>   increasing levels of semantic depth.

Thus, Azure recommends using Neural Networks for image classification. Remember, that the goal of the exam is to test your capacity to design data science solution **using Azure** so better to use their official documentation as a reference.

And comparing to the other solutions:

1. You create an Azure notebook that supports the Microsoft Cognitive
   Toolkit.
2. You create a Machine Learning experiment that implements
   the Multiclass Decision Jungle module.
3. You create an endpoint to the
   Computer vision API.
4. You create a Machine Learning experiment that
   implements the Multiclass Neural Network module.
5. You create an Azure
   notebook that supports the Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit.

There are only 2 Azure ML Studio modules, and as the question is about constructing a **workflow** I guess we can only choose between them. (CNTK is actually the best solution as it allows constructing a deep neural network with ReLU whereas AML Studio doesn't, and API call is not about data science at all).

Finally, I do agree with the other contributors that the question is absurd. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is indeed part of a series of questions that present the same scenario with multiple options. Both of the solutions approach the problem as a multi-class classification problem, which is correct. However, the key element here is dimensionality.

Your inputs (images) are highly dimensional which requires a deep learning approach in order to be effective. A decision jungle won't be able to learn effectively in such a high dimensional feature space, where a NN has higher chances to do so.

I hope it helps.